# Remove last comma in Two Dimensional Array using for loop

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I can't avoid printing the last comma:

```
 public void displayArrayMethod(int array[][])
        {
            for(int row=0; row<array.length; row++)
            {
                for(int column=0; column<array[row].length; column++)
                {
                    System.out.print(array[row][column]+",");
                }
            }
        }
```

output:
`1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of looking for a way to get rid of the last comma, it would be much easier to avoid having it in the first place. One way to do so is to let Java's streams do the heavy lifting instead of you having to write loops yourself:

```
public void displayArrayMethod(int array[][]) {
    System.out.print(Arrays.stream(array)
              .flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)
              .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
              .collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This loop checks for the last column before appending the comma.

EDIT: Added full implementation to help find possible differences from user's that could be causing the problem in his comment. This code returns `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`

```
public class Sandbox { //opens class 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] array = {
                {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
        };
        displayArrayMethod(array);
        System.out.println("wait");
    }

    public static void displayArrayMethod(int array[][]) {
        for(int row=0; row<array.length; row++)
        {
            if(row == array[row].length - 1 && column == array[row].length - 1)
            {
                if(column == array[row].length - 1) 
                {
                   System.out.print(array[row][column]);
                } 
                else 
                {
                   System.out.print(array[row][column]+",");
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it shows this error `The primitive type int of column does not have a field length`

Comment: Missed that. Thanks!

Comment: it's not working,,,, it's showing this output: `1,2,34,5,67,8,9`

Comment: it's not working,,,, it's showing this output: `1,2,34,5,67,8,9` and my array is: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}

Comment: Not sure why unless you've changed something else. I just ran your array and it works fine. I can update the full code if you like or add a screenshot.

Comment: `public class MultiDimentionalArray {
public static void main(String[] args) {   
int [][] array = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}};                                     myArray.displayArrayMethod(array);   }                                                                                        public static void displayArrayMethod(int array[][])
  { 
for(int row=0; row<array.length; row++) { for(int column=0; column<array[row].length-1; column++) {
  System.out.print(array[row][column]+",");
    }
System.out.print(array[row][array[row].length-1]);
  }
  }}`

Comment: All that is required is to change the condition:
if(row == array[row].length - 1 && column == array[row].length - 1) I have updated my code with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in several ways...

opt1: result.substring(0, result.length() - 1)

opt2:  Arrays.deepToString(x) not too much what you need, but almost the same

opt3:  stringBuilder (john skeet way...)

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final int[][] x = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };
    displayArrayMethod(x);
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(x));
    displayArrayMethod2(x);
}

private static void displayArrayMethod2(final int[][] x) {
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String prefix = "";

    for (final int[] element : x) {
        for (final int element2 : element) {
            sb.append(prefix);
            prefix = ",";
            sb.append(element2);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}

public static void displayArrayMethod(final int array[][]) {
    String result = "";
    for (final int[] element : array) {
        for (final int element2 : element) {
            result += element2 + ",";
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result.substring(0, result.length() - 1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int column=0; column<array[row].length-1; column++){
   System.out.print(array[row][column]+",");
}
System.out.print(array[row][array[row].length-1];
```

Comment: Showing error `Exception in thread "main" 1,2,java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
 at com.kanon.MultiDimentionalArray.MultiDimentionalArray.displayArrayMethod(MultiDimentionalArray.java:61)
 at com.kanon.MultiDimentionalArray.MultiDimentionalArray.main(MultiDimentionalArray.java:28)`

Comment: updated System.out.print(array[row][array[row].length-1];

Comment: not working is showing like this output: `1,2,34,5,67,8,9` and my array is: `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}`

Comment: You need to read your question (you said that you have int[][]) and use this algorithm (I change only the column loop) to find your final solution... You can't just copy-paste...